# Требуются ли тут запятые? И почему?

Tags: пунктуация

Мы как дураки сидели один час.

Я как дурак сидел один час.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это сравнение (что логичнее) - то запятые нужны. В большинстве примеров из гугл-книг есть запятые.

Разница в смысле такая:

*Мы, как дураки, сидели один час.* = *Мы, как будто дураки, сидели один час.* || Сравнение.

*Мы как дураки сидели один час.* = *Мы, являясь дураками, сидели один час.* = *Мы дураки - просидели целый час зря.*

Answer (score 2):

1) **Разницы в смысле никакой.** Используя это сравнение, автор иронично оценивает свое не очень умное поведение.

2) **В текстах встречаются оба варианта**:

Насчёт того, что я **как дурак** просидел в этой кладовке часа два. [Андрей Геласимов. Фокс Малдер похож на свинью (2001)]

― Возьмите больше, ― сказал Фред. Но я, **как дурак**, запротестовал. Фред посмотрел на меня с любопытством. [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

А то мы, **как дураки**, уже начали готовиться. [коллективный. Форум: АЭС Фукусима. Технические условия на проведение стресс-тестов (2011)]

Эти двое сидят за столом и улыбаются **как дураки**, а по субботам гуляют в парке и катаются на карусели. [Каринэ Арутюнова. Дочери Евы // «Сибирские огни», 2013]

3) Как выбрать? **Выбор делается по структуре предложения.**

Если оборот не обособляется, то он выделяется логическим ударением и является обстоятельством образа действия (стою по-дурацки).

Если это попутное замечание/сравнение, которое можно убрать из распространенного предложения, то оборот обособляется.

4) **Решение задачи**

Желательно для ясности добавить контекст, например:

*Мы, **как дураки**, просидели здесь целый час, а они так и не пришли* (попутное сравнение).

*Я **как дурАк** просидел здесь целый  час* (логическое выделение оборота).

Comment: Не согласен с вами. Разница есть в смысле. Сравнительные обороты обособляются. Без запятой "как" выражает предмет. Например: биология как наука; он как учёный; человек как личность. То есть можно вставить "являясь". Большинство примеров "я как дурак" из гугл-книг с запятыми.

Comment: Не надо мешать разные темы. В приведенном примере  речь идет об уподоблении (сравнении), когда обособленный оборот мы отличаем от необособленного обстоятельства. Вы же приводите примеры из темы отождествления (рассматривая,  считая.) Этот оборот можно отнести к устойчивым,  и он достаточно часто не обособляется, но обособление при этом  не отменяется. В каждом конкретном предложении оборот занимает или позицию обстоятельства, или позицию попутного сравнения, поэтому требуется анализ. Что же мы, всё будем из гугл-книг списывать?

Comment: Без запятых "как" становится аналогом английского слова "as", при котором уже не идёт чисто сравнение и можно подставить "являясь", "в виде". На самом деле тема "отождествления" не ограничена редкими случаями. Возможно, что ваша "позиция обстоятельства" неявно и является той же темой в чуть другом ракурсе. Гугл-книги - это и есть литература. В ней же заложенные правила языка, и на неё же ссылается gramota.ru. В базе гугл есть не только классика, а и старинные книги с частым употреблением твёрдого знака.

Comment: Я ничего не имею против гугл-книг, просто списывать нехорошо. Думаю, что вам нужно почитать Розенталя  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147  Обратите внимание на п. 3.1. и 4.1.  В них как раз рассматривается тема уподобления (сравнения), когда нужно выбрать обособленный оборот или необособленное обстоятельство.  Вообще говоря,  в ответах нужно приводить ссылки на официальные источники, и Розенталь  здесь наиболее авторитетен. Спорные вопросы, разные мнения должны решаться с использованием источников.

Comment: После прочтения 4.1 понимаю, что мы с вами говорим об одном и том же. И является это тем же "отождествлением", только в очень неявном ракурсе. Но при этом обстоятельстве смысл всё же меняется. То есть по Розенталю это равно "мы сидели дураками" - именно то значение, которое я описал в ответе.

Comment: Говорим, но  на разных языках.  Нет здесь разного значения, но есть разная структурная грамматика. А Т.п. -  это формальная проверка, и сам Розенталь говорит о том же. И сказал бы он, наверное, больше, если бы ему было позволено это сделать.   Всё ваше разное значение - эта разная постановка логических ударений в разных по структуре предложениях.  Писатели, выбирающие разную форму, делают это интуитивно. Так что выбирайте: или  художественная интуиция писателя, или понимание грамматических основ на более высоком (не чисто формальном) уровне.

Comment: Формальная проверка, но которая выражает смысловую суть. Не было бы никакой разницы в смысле - не было бы нужды писать без запятых. Мне кажется, что писатели понимают эту разницу, а не пишут "от фонаря". В английском эта разница очевидна. То есть зная её можно правильно писать и в русском. Сравнить: как град посыпалась - градом посыпалась; посыпалась, как град - как будто град. Серьёзно никакой разницы в смысле? Просто здесь она явная, а в других примерах её понять гораздо сложнее и для этого нужно подставлять другие слова.

Comment: @Sharon  _Разнице в смысле никакой._ Мне кажется, что надо _разницЫ._

Comment: @Римма Михайлова  Спасибо, Римма, заходите чаще, а то все куда-то пропали.

Comment: Если разницы в смысле никакой, то контекст вами не поможет. Нет? Это единственное, что меня смущает в вашем ответе.

Comment: @behemothus Это не то чтобы контекст. Я распространила предложения, чтобы их структура различалась и можно было выбрать один из вариантов.  В вопросе по интонации оба варианта подходят. Смысл же один: я вел себя глупо, мы вели себя как дураки, были похожи на дураков. Это как раз принцип сравнения: похожи по какому-то признаку, но при этом не являемся дураками и не считаем себя дураками. С другой стороны, кто-то посторонний может считать персонажа дураком (глупым человеком). Например, он меня как дурака заваливает работой, а платит при этом копейки. Это уже отождествление, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 1):

**Вместо вступления**

Я тоже хотела ответить на этот вопрос, для чего заглянула в Нацкорпус, после чего убедилась, что существуют обе формы письма. Надо было подумать, в чем их различие, но думать не пришлось, так как ответ был сразу принят. Конечно, я с интересом прочитала его – и не поняла ничего. Ну ни словечка, правда же.

На мой собственный ответ поступило так много комментариев, что ответить на них я попробую, написав второй ответ.

**Тождество и сравнение** –  принципиально разные вещи.  **Тождество** – это **равенство** двух предметов, а **сравнение** (уподобление) – это их **сходство по определенным признакам**  (например, тропинка не равна змее, но она вьется как змея).

1) **Тождество**  рассматривается в теме обособленных приложений с союзом КАК, в этом случае оборот имеет значение причины и обособляется. **Отождествление** – это  не тождество, а приравнивание одного предмета к другому (но не по сходству, а по другим признакам). В действительности же эти предметы могут быть не равны.

Например, сравним два предложения:  (1) *Как врач, я не советую употреблять это лекарство длительное время.* Это тождество, здесь такой смысл: так как я врач, то я разбираюсь в лекарствах.

Но тот же человек  (врач по профессии) может сказать следующее:  (2) *А вот на сладости тебе налегать не стоит, это я как врач говорю .* Здесь значение «в качестве врача», потому что он же не только врач, но и, к примеру,  друг семьи, близкий родственник или еще кто, но в данном случае высказывает свое мнение именно как врач.

Таким образом, в этой теме надо различать **тождество с причинным значением** (обособление) и **отождествление** (рассматриваю, считаю, приравниваю, отождествляю, говорю от имени) без обособления.  Иногда это сделать не так просто,  что и видно из рассмотренного примера.

Вот еще пример на  эту тему.   (3) *Ждали мы недолго. Как родных, нас приняли в первую очередь.*  Это **тождество**: так как мы родственники, то у нас были привилегии .  (4) **Они принимали нас  как родных.** Это **отождествление**, приравнивание.  В действительности мы не родственники, но отнеслись к нам так, как будто мы были  их роднёй.

Из приведенных примеров ясно, **как тождество и отождествление различаются по смыслу**. Надо сказать, что различие вполне ощутимое.

2)  **А что можно сказать про оборот «как дурак»**,  это тождество/отождествление или сравнение? Я сидел, ***так как я дурак***?  Или я сидел там ***в качестве дурака***?
Разумеется, нет.

В данном случае это именно **сравнение**, уподобление. Имеется в виду, что  я веду себя глупо, что  свойственно дуракам, но в действительности **я, конечно же, умный  человек, с дураком себя не отождествляю.**

И вот эта задача (обособление сравнительного оборота) тоже **имеет два решения**, но различие между ними **не смысловое, а структурное**, оно связано с построением  предложения. Можно обособить оборот, тогда это будет **попутное сравнение**, отнесенное на второй план речи. А необособленный оборот будет **выделен логическим ударением,** он входит в основной состав предложения. Вот и всё "смысловое различие".

В каждом случае **автор  так строит текст**, чтобы было удобно выбрать нужный ему вариант. Первый случай  характерен **для распространенных предложений**,  основное содержание которых  с  оборотом не связано. Но если предложение **короткое**, то эмоциональная оценка подчеркивается, выступает на первый план.

Comment: *Надо было подумать, в чем их различие, но думать не пришлось, так как ответ был сразу принят. Конечно, я с интересом прочитала его – и не поняла ничего. Ну ни словечка, правда же.* - Вы тоже это заметили?!)))

Comment: @Sharon "Сравнение и отождествление" - вот эти 2 варианта и расписал в ответе. Естественно, что сравнение тут более логично.

Comment: @ В следующий раз (это общее пожелание к Вашим ответам) пишите понятнее.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что разница есть, но очень слабая, что действительно делает варианты семантически почти тождественными. 
В этой ситуации вариант без запятых кажется мне предпочтительным в любом контексте, не слишком фантастическом, конечно.

Опускаю теорию, она есть у sharon.

По вариантам.
~1. Обособление **обязательно** только в одном случае. Если есть некие реальные дураки, который тоже попадали в такую ситуацию. 
Тогда: ***Мы, как (и те) дураки, сидели час...***
Этот-то вариант я и отношу к фантастическим.

~2. Автор хочет сказать ***"сидели, как дураки..."*** - в том смысле что дураки сидят неким особенным образом. Тогда явное сравнение. Случай, на мой взгляд реальный, но несколько забавный.

~3. И, наконец, ***"сидели как дураки"*** - здесь о том, что сам факт вынужденного (или, наоборот, ненужного в той ситуации) сидения приравнивает сидящего к дуракам. Это можно трактовать и как сравнение, но более похоже на отождествление. Поскольку вариант этого понимания наиболее естественный, то лучше его и оформлять так, чтобы не было путаницы с 1. и 2.

//---
В порядке обсуждения.

Вопрос дифференциации уподобления, сравнения, приравнивания и отождествления на самом деле весьма непрост и излагается порой весьма противоречиво. Сейчас намечается тенденция в спорных случаях трактовать идти по наиболее простому пути - обособлять всегда, когда есть хоть малейший мотив для этого, то есть при малейших признаках сравнения.

Это не совсем верно, мне кажется. Я бы этот подход чуть-чуть изсенил. Для себя я решил, что в таких спорных случаях стоит руководствоваться другим "правилом". Если объект сравнения/уподобления/отождествления/приравнивания реален ("Я, как доктор, спортсмен, велосипедист" - словно доктор, не будучи им)  -  сравнение/уподобление.

Если же реальности нет ("Я как космонавт, тигр, мать Тереза"), то нет и сравнения. Дополнительные аргумент тут тот, что такие случаи чаще всего входят в состав сказуемого.

Повторяю: это все в спорных случаях! Там, где дифференциация не представляет трудностей ("в качестве", например, или при неразрывной связи со сказуемым) школьные правила работают, я на них не покушаюсь.